# How to select the first item in a ListView by default

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

When my app loads, I want the first item in the listview to already be selected. how can I do this?

Comment: What do you consider to be selected? What does `selected` mean to you?

Comment: the highlight should be on the first cell, as if it was clicked (or even better, perform a click)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

in your list view activity

```
getListView().setSelection(0);
```

Comment: I did listView.setSelection(0) but that didn't select my item.

Comment: This particular step did not work for me! How come the answer is marked as correct if it did not work for you either?

Comment: Yes, i have the same problem ... listView.setSelection(0) doesn't work. But the answer is marked as OK. If the user who put the question fix it, please share with us.

Comment: did you guys call setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); on your list first?  Also that view needs to be implementing the checkable interface.